# Switching from a VM: How much “overhead” does the desktop version add versus the server version?

Tags: virtualization, desktop-environments

I usually use Ubuntu on VitrualBox machines and use the server distro.  I’m considering installing Ubuntu directly to the hardware, but I’m concerned about not having a GUI option at all.

With the desktop version I’m not concerned about disk space, but performance.  Does it have a significant effect on overall performance?  Or am I worrying too much?  Won’t I get a performance boost by not running in a VM anymore?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) Please take a look at the "RAM usage of different flavors of Ubuntu 18.04" chart in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system meets the [minimum requirement for Ubuntu Desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

The Ubuntu Desktop installer has a "Try Ubuntu" environment specifically so you can test Ubuntu with your hardware **before** committing to an install. Test your wifi, your network connection, printers and other peripherals...and your system performance.